# how to limit text length 'file_get_contents' in php and provide 'Read more' link

Tags: php

I want to read the first 200 characters from a local file, however, my code is reading all the content of my text file.

```
<?php
     $connection= new mysqli($DB_host,$DB_user,$DB_pass,$DB_name);
     $query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM new_record ORDER BY id");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $fileName = $row['name'];
        $fileContents = file_get_contents("txt/$fileName");
        echo ("$fileContents");
    }
?>
```

Comment: you can try : echo substr($fileContens,0,200);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`file_get_contents()` has a `$maxlen` parameter.

Please refer to the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).